# C++ assembly code compilation interference - execution changed

Tags: c++, assembly, compilation, cpu-registers, function-call

I am writing some code in assembly and use it within c++/g++ code running under linux-64bit (gcc version 4.4.1 [gcc-4_4-branch revision 150839]  (SUSE Linux)). Assembly code runs faultless but surrounding c++ code delivers different results (no crash, just 4x slower and slightly different computation result), depending upon implementation/omission of the assembly code (i.e. reduced code snippet).

I removed everything superfluous and the code snippet below is all thats implemented right now. Only push and pops and storage of xmmx, no more than that. BTW. if I only store and restore xmmx in the snippet, without the rbx,rsi,rdi,rbp push/pops the c++ code works fine again. Calling convention require rbx,rdi,rsi and rbp to remain intact, thus they are saved. If I add other registers (rax, rcx, rdx, ... with additional push & pops), result is the same - c++ code not working properly anymore. Unfortunately, I need these regs in the (here: omitted) assembly code.

Assembly debugging around implemented code snippet did not show any obvious reason. Assume that it is in general a differently compiled code but not that easy the compare (Complete Code is several ten thousand lines) Must be I am missing something obvious or have to consider something during compilation.

Any suggestions ? Thanks

```
extern "C" void store_xmmx();
extern "C" void restore_xmmx();
//
void xmmx_manipulation_cpp_not_working()
{
// cpp-Code before Assembly, same as in working function
//
store_xmmx();
// assembly code here, but removed from source for debugging
// cpp still executes differently with simple pushes and pops
restore_xmmx();
//
// cpp-Code after Assembly, same as in working function
};
void xmmx_manipulation_cpp_working()
{
// cpp-Code before Assembly, same as in not working function
//
// store_xmmx(); 
// assembly code 
// restore_xmmx(); 
//
// cpp-Code after Assembly, same as in not working function
};
//
//Assembly Code:
//
align 16
global store_xmmx
store_xmmx:
pop  r8         
push rbp
push rsi
push rdi
push rbx
sub     rsp,200h        
fxsave  [rsp]       
push r8            
ret
align 16
global restore_xmmx
restore_xmmx:
pop  r8         
fxrstor [rsp]
fwait
add  rsp,200h
pop  rbx
pop  rdi
pop  rsi
pop  rbp  
push r8            
ret
```

Comment: You are returning with `rsp` changed, that's a no-no. The caller may very well address items on the stack relative to `rsp` and you blow that up. Funnily enough the abi docs don't mention that, but I am pretty sure gcc counts on that.

Comment: Which processor did you say you were using?  After all, assembly language is usually specific to a processor.

Comment: @Thomas Matthews - I am using Intel 2500K, 64 bit

Comment: @Jester - basically agree, there may be an impact. However, I would assume the program to crash which it does not when running over hours. It should, as return adresses would not be properly popped. The question is - how can the assumption - stack "changed" be tested/checked to find a solution ?

Comment: @Jester - What would be a reason for the compiler to use the stack before calling the function store_xmmx and reusing some part of it before the stack is restored with restore_xmmx ? I thought the relevant registers (rbp, rsi, rdi, rbx) are left untouched by convention to avoid usage of the stack ...

Comment: So coming closer to solve the issue - big difference if I use cout << endl;(bad) or cout << "\n";(good) in the Code, although the issue above is not clear yet. Changed asm code above to something like this: void fx_store() {
 long long adr; assert(fxi>=0);assert(fxi<20);
 adr=(long long) &fxdatas[fxi];
 asm ("fxsave (%0) \n\t" : : "r" (adr) );
 fxi+=1;};
void fx_restore() { long long adr;
  assert(fxi>=0); assert(fxi<=20); fxi-=1;
  adr=(long long) &fxdatas[fxi];  asm ("fxrstor (%0) \n\t" : : "r"(adr) );
  asm ("fwait\n\t");
}; -- did not help although; maybe cause "cout" issue not resolve yet